# Primefaces Paginator always jumping to page 1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, pagination

In PF 4.0, how do you make the paginator go to the correct page after updating a datatable and applying `oncomplete="dt1Widget.filter()"`?

A button in a dialog is supposed to save a certain element, then update the datatable, again apply the filters (as saved by my own DataTableRenderer), and stay on the page I was on when I opened the dialog. That means I filter by certain criteria, go to page 7, edit an element, press save and still want to be on page 7 afterwards.

My datatable

```
<p:dataTable id="dt1" var="tVar" value="#{regelBean.queriedElements}" scrollable="false"
  paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" rows="10"
  rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,100" paginatorPosition="bottom" widgetVar="dt1Widget"
  filteredValue="#{regelBean.filteredElements}" first="#{regelBean.paginatorFirst}">
  ...
  <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{regelBean.onPageChange}"/>
```

Button inside the dialog

```
<p:commandButton value="Speichern #{regelBean.paginatorFirst}" 
  update="@form :form1:dt1" actionListener="#{regelBean.save}" 
  oncomplete="dt1Widget.filter(); dt1Widget.getPaginator().setPage(#{regelBean.paginatorPage});"/>
```

even tried this

```
public int getPaginatorPage() {
  DataTable d = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":form1:dt1");
  System.out.println("d.first " + d.getFirst()); // always 20 since I was on page 3
  return d.getFirst()/10;
}
```

`paginatorFirst` on the button label is 20 when I am on page 3 (kind of expected). After saving, I will always land on page 1. Quick help is really appreciated, as I will stop working on this project in 2 days and would like to fix this issue until then. Thanks

**EDIT**
What the heck is going on here? I tried

```
<p:commandButton value="x" update=":form1:dt1" 
  onstart="#{regelBean.saveFirst()}; alert('A'); " 
  oncomplete="dt1Widget.filter(); #{regelBean.oncompl()}; alert('! #{regelBean.paginatorFirst} !');"/>
```

and saveFirst() is randomly (not) called. Besides, until the second alert everything is alright. But AFTER the second alert, I am sent to page 1. When I reload the page, I will land on page 3...

Comment: Binding the "first" attribute like you did should do the trick and no other things should be necessary. dt1Widget.getPaginator().setPage(#{regelBean.paginatorPage}); is not needed and may in fact cause trouble

Comment: see my edit. Moreover, I took out `paginator.setPage()` as I realized it will only delegate to `dt.setFirst()`. No more paginator logic in my code left, only `first`

Comment: I noticed this behavior, too (using Primefaces 5.2). I opened a new issue so it might be fixed in a future version: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/517